# what's the difference between light rosin and dark rosin?

Tags: strings, equipment

I see two basic kinds of rosin available, light rosin and dark rosin. What's the difference between these?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer may surprise you:

- colour

Really, it gives you the option to avoid light coloured rosin dust on your instrument. Useful if you have a very dark instrument.